# Array Testing of an Entire Column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking to perform multiple tests on 1 column of data. I want the test to return Pass if every cell in the column meets the requirements and Fail if only one cell fails the requirements. I'd like to have the pass or fail come up only in 1 cell as opposed to having a pass/fail next to each cell. For example, if the entire column has cells that are 6 digits long and numeric then the entire column would pass. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for the specific case you mentioned. This formula will return "Pass" if all the values in `A1:A5` are 6-digit numbers.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$1:$A$5)=6)*ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$5))=COUNTA($A$1:$A$5),"Pass","Fail")
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` function allows you to check multiple conditions throughout an array. As it is set up here, it essentially counts the number of cells that meet both conditions. This count is then compared to the count of values in the range (`COUNTA`) to determine whether the range passes or fails.